# Нужны ли запятые между сказуемыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

"(...) чтобы действовать и достигать своих целей и не терять время зря".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые не нужны, потому что глаголы не однородны, они используются *без* или *с разными* дополнениями. *Действовать, достигать **целей*** и *не терять **времени**.* Таким образом, два И связывают не однородные между собой члены предложения.

Comment: "Действовать" не относится к "целям", а в остальном согласен.

Comment: Да, точно, промашка вышла, спасибо!